# Data factory - Integration runtime status alert

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-alerts

Am having multiple self hosted Integration Runtimes in my data factory. I need an alert rule via Mail, once the status changes from `Running` to `Limited` or anything else than `Running`:
[image]

Unfortunately, i can't any matching metric for my case - any ideas how to solve this?
[image]

**Example:**
In this case I'd like to get a mail every hour, since one integration runtime is not `Running`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data factory Alert rules does not provide any specific alert rule to check the status of Integration runtime.**

To achieve your goal, you need to create a logic app to send mail when Integration runtime in not running with the help of Rest API.

- Create a Logic app and create a workflow in it and go to designer mode.
- Take a recurrence as trigger and set interval and frequency of 3 Minutes.
  [image]
- Then take an HTTP request to [get list of Integration runtimes in Data factory by Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/integration-runtimes/list-by-factory?tabs=HTTP&tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-0)
  [image]
- Then take for each loop to iterate on the output of previous HTTP response with value `body('HTTP').value`
  [image]
- Under for each loop take another HTTP request to [get status of Integration runtime by Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/integration-runtimes/get-status?tabs=HTTP#code-try-0). use below dynamic expression in URL.

```json
concat('https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SubscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/<DF-name>/integrationRuntimes/',item().name,'/getStatus?api-version=2018-06-01')
```

[image]

- Then take an if condition to send mail if state is other than online `body('HTTP_1').properties.state`
  [image]
- In true take a Send an email (V2) 1 to send email sing in with you email and appropriate values as below.
  [image]

***Output:***

> Note: I checked for whether state is equal to online.

**Got an email**
[image]